# How to authenticate login with a pre-hashed mysql password in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication, passwords

So, in my mysql database, I have a whole table for users which contains hashed (with the `PASSWORD()` mysql function) passwords. In C#, I made a program that can insert new records into the database and display existing ones.

Now I'm at the stage when I want to make a login, which checks if the entered data (username and password) equal to the ones that are in the users table. (The users table contains id, username, password columns.)

What I tried so far:

In my class that is for database operations:
(The `c.conn`, `c.open()`, `c.close()` are just functions defined by me in a class called Connect.)

```
public bool logIn(string usrName, string pswd)
        {
            bool success = false;
            string dbusrname; string dbpswd;
            c.open();
            string hashedEnteredPswd = "PASSWORD(@password);";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(hashedEnteredPswd, c.conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pswd);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            c.close();
            query = "SELECT * FROM admins;";
            c.open();
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, c.conn);
            var reader=cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                dbusrname = reader["users"].ToString();
                dbpswd = reader["password"].ToString();
                if (dbusrname == usrName && dbpswd == hashedEnteredPswd)
                {
                    success = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    success = false;
                }
            }
            c.close();
            return success;
        }
```

In the code of my form:

```
        private void Container_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            c.open();
            clearPanels();
            panelLogIn.Visible = true;
        }

        private void buttonLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dbops.logIn(textBoxUID.Text, textBoxPSWD.Text))
            {
                clearPanels();
                panelMain.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

In my misery, I tried hashing the entered password with a mysql function in C#(I know, I know...)

Ofc when If I run this, I get the following exception: `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'PROCEDURE test.PASSWORD does not exist'` which is expected and I understand why it doesn't work.

But then, how should do this correctly? How on earth do I make it work?

Comment: should you not need to do `SELECT PASSWORD(@password);`? Also you need to store the value from your query, otherwise `hashedEnteredPswd` will literally equal `PASSWORD(@password);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mentions (though nothing official), that mysql Password function does the following

```
"*" + SHA1(SHA1(pass))
```

This is not to be relied upon.

You could try the following though (it's not advised, but it might solve your problem).

```
// remove the previous commands 
query = "SELECT * FROM admins Where password = PASSWORD(@password);
```

Then create the parameter for the query.

Best way to do it though, would be to hash it yourself with a modern hashing algorithm before inserting it into the database, and rehash it before checking it. Ignore the password function altogether.

Answer (score 0):

By your code, you check each user in the database and compare it.
That's not efficient.

The "SQL way" to do that is querying exactly what you need.

```sql
string query = "SELECT user FROM admins WHERE username = " + username + " AND password = " + password;
```

**(Note that this solution is not safe againts SQL injections and not elegent, [Learn more about adding parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements))**

Regarding your error, You have tried to hash using PASSWORD function that has been deprecated for version > 5.7.5.
[Here are some other ways to hash your passwords.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html)

Comment: It's a much easier and more simple way than mine. I just had to add a mysql hash function to the query and check if it returned any rows. It works perfectly now, thanks mate!